# Creating a Delay in lua

Tags: sockets, loops, lua, io

I'm making a IRC client using LUA. I'm using the the libraries that came with "Lua for Windows ". So I'm using luasocket for the comms and IUP for the UI bits.

The problem I'm having is that I'm getting stuck in a loop when I read the IO. I tried the timer in IUP but that didn't seem to work.

I'm was looking for a way to delay the IO read loop.

I set the time out for the reads to 0 and that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably making a blocking read on a TCP socket inside the GUI thread. That will lock up your whole application if you do not receive the expected data in a timely manner. Either perform the socket I/O in a separate thread (see [Lua Lanes](http://luaforge.net/projects/lanes/)) or use non-blocking I/O (see [`settimeout`](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/tcp.html#settimeout)).

The [Kepler Project](http://www.keplerproject.org/) is a great resource for guidance on networking applications with Lua, but it is focused on web applications versus an IRC client. For example, the [Copas](http://keplerproject.github.com/copas/) library uses [Lua coroutines](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CoroutinesTutorial) to handle multiple TCP connections.

Now if you really just wanted to know how to create a delay in Lua, then the [Sleep Function](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SleepFunction) article in the [lua-users wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/) should provide all the information you need.

Comment: Thanks dropping the time out on the reads helped. So no need for a delay.